# Emacs: no such file or directory, pdflatex.

Tags: pdftex, emacs

I installed LaTex preview pane in emacs, but when I pressed `M-p`, it show no such file. Here is the message in the message buffer.

```
Updating LaTeX Preview Pane
lpp/invoke-pdf-latex-command: Searching for program: no such file or directory, pdflatex
Updating LaTeX Preview Pane
Error running timer `latex-preview-pane-update': (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "pdflatex")
```

And here is my `.emacs` configuration for LaTex mode.

```
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t) 
(setenv "PATH" "/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH" t)
(latex-preview-pane-enable)
```

Answer (score 2):

In emacs, the `PATH` environment variable and the `exec-path` Lisp variable are two different things.  I recommend using `exec-path-from-shell` to do away with the confusion once and for all:

```lisp
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :config (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Otherwise, you can maintain it manually with a simple `add-to-list`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin")
```